# Strange behavior with debounced/throttled function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I need to call, every time a textbox value changes.  However, it initializes an AJAX call, so I need to not run the script on every keystroke.

I wrote the following function as a proof of concept:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scheduledChange;
    function triggerLinkChange(value, debounce) {
        clearTimeout(scheduledChange);
        scheduledChange = setTimeout(function(val) {
            alert("value: "+val);
        }(value), debounce);
    }
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        triggerLinkChange($(this).val(),3000);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the delay seems to not be working, properly.  I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, as it appears to have a slight delay for the first call (maybe), but then fires with every keypress.

Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/, it should solve your problem.

Comment: The first argument in your `setTimeout` is undefined since that function will return undefined.

Comment: (value) after the function expression causes the function to be executed right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function that you declare in the timeout immediately, instead of passing it to the function.

However, it will actually work without binding or passing `value` to the function, because the variable is in scope anyway:

```
    scheduledChange = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("value: " + value);
    }, debounce);
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RbLRu/

Answer (score 2):

Seems too complicated ?

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var self = this;

    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );

    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
        // do ajax, 3 seconds seems like lot here

        $.get('url', {value : self.value}, callback);

    }, 3000));

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the enhancement that saves me a global variable.  I like this solution, but unfortunately I'll still need to break out into a function, because this is a UFD combobox, and I need to trigger the change under a few different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way is to have a variable like this (pseudo-code because I am just typing it out here):

```
    var myTrigger; 

    $('input').keyup(function(){
            // Cancel the countdown to do the ajax
            window.clearTimeout(myTrigger);
            // Now reset it to trigger in 3 seconds unless another key is pressed
            myTrigger = window.setTimeout(function () { DoAjax(); }, 3000);
         }
    });
```

Comment: No dice... This sends the value at the beginning of the debounce period.  so if I type Hello and take 5 seconds, the triggerLinkChange function receives "Hel", because the keyups for 'l' and 'o' were blocked.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to do it like an autocomplete? I'll update my answer.